# Combinations from a Single Table, Grouped By a Column Value

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations

I have a table of values:

```
+-----+-------+
| ID  | STATE |
+-----+-------+
|  1  |   AL  |
|  1  |   AZ  |
|  1  |   MI  |
|  2  |   TX  |
|  2  |   TN  |
|  2  |   MO  |
|  2  |   ND  |
And many, many more...
```

How do I write a query that generates all of the possible state combinations for each individual ID?  So the results are like:

```
+-----+-------------+
| ID  | COMBINATION |
+-----+-------------+
|  1  | AL, AZ      |
|  1  | AL, MI      |
|  1  | AZ, MI      |
|  1  | AL, AZ, MI  |
|  2  | TX, TN      |
|  2  | TX, MO      |
|  2  | TX, ND      |
|  2  | TN, MO      |
|  2  | TN, ND      |
  And so on...
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Ravshan got me thinking that I do not want permutations but, bonus if the combination string is in alphabetical order.

Comment: "AL, AZ, MI" and "MI, AL, AZ" - is the same combination or not?

Comment: Those would be considered the same and the query should return only one. 
 Combinations only.  *NOT* Permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using hierarchical queries - here's one using the old-style `connect by`:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'AL' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, 'AZ' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, 'MI' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 'TX' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 'TN' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 'MO' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 'ND' state FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 'OH' state FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       state,
       ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(state, ','), ',') combinations,
       LEVEL
FROM   (SELECT id,
               state,
               count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) state_cnt
        FROM your_table)
WHERE  state_cnt = 1
OR     (state_cnt > 1 AND LEVEL > 1)
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ID
           AND PRIOR state < state
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;

        ID STATE COMBINATIONS      LEVEL
---------- ----- ------------ ----------
         1 AZ    AL,AZ                 2
         1 MI    AL,AZ,MI              3
         1 MI    AL,MI                 2
         1 MI    AZ,MI                 2
         2 TX    TN,TX                 2
         2 TX    MO,TX                 2
         2 TN    MO,TN                 2
         2 TX    MO,TN,TX              3
         2 ND    MO,ND                 2
         2 TX    MO,ND,TX              3
         2 TN    MO,ND,TN              3
         2 TX    MO,ND,TN,TX           4
         2 TX    ND,TX                 2
         2 TN    ND,TN                 2
         2 TX    ND,TN,TX              3
         3 OH    OH                    1
```

*The `prior sys_guid() is not null` condition in the connect by clause is required to ensure we're looping over the correct rows (if you were to omit it, the result would contain many extra rows).*

I've excluded rows with just a single state in the output - except if the id only listed a single state. You may or may not want to include single states in the output, in which case, you can remove the predicates entirely.