# Sets From a Single Table, Grouped By a Column

Tags: oracle, string-concatenation

I have a table:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| GROUP | State | Priority |
+-------+-------+----------+
|   1   |  MI   |     1    |
|   1   |  IA   |     2    |
|   1   |  CA   |     3    |
|   1   |  ND   |     4    |
|   1   |  AZ   |     5    |
|   2   |  IA   |     2    |
|   2   |  NJ   |     1    |
|   2   |  NH   |     3    |

And so on...
```

How do I write a query that makes all the sets of the states by group, in priority order?  Like so:

```
+-------+--------------------+
| GROUP |        SET         |
+-------+--------------------+
|   1   | MI                 |
|   1   | MI, IA             |
|   1   | MI, IA, CA         |
|   1   | MI, IA, CA, ND     |
|   1   | MI, IA, CA, ND, AZ |
|   2   | NJ                 |
|   2   | NJ, IA             |
|   2   | NJ, IA, NH         |
+-------+--------------------+
```

This is similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397808/combinations-from-a-single-table-grouped-by-a-column-value) and I've tried to modify that solution but, I'm just a forty watt bulb and it's a sixty watt problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem actually looks simpler than the answer to the question you linked, which is an excellent solution to that problem. Nevertheless, this uses the same hierarchical queries, with `connect by`

If it is the case that `priority` is always a continuous sequence of numbers, this will work

```
SELECT t.grp, level, ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(state,','),',')   as "set"  
   from  t 
   start with priority = 1
 connect by   priority = prior priority + 1
            and grp = prior grp
```

However, if that's not always true, we would require  `row_number()` to define the sequence based on the order of priority ( which need not be consecutive integer)

```
with t2 AS
( 
  select t.*, row_number() 
        over ( partition by grp order by priority) as rn from t
)
SELECT t2.grp, ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(state,','),',')   as "set"
   from  t2 
   start with priority = 1
 connect by   rn = prior rn + 1
            and grp = prior grp
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64d86e8eb52d1db906001972b54697cd)

Comment: Terrific!  This is a great, elegant answer!  Thanks so much, Kaushik!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has already been answered, but I wanted to see if I could do this using ANSI standard syntax. "connect by" is an Oracle only feature, the following will work on multiple databases:

```
WITH
    -- ASET is just setting up the sample dataset
    aset AS
        (SELECT 1 AS grp, 'MI' AS state, 1 AS priority FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS grp, 'IA', 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS grp, 'CA', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS grp, 'ND', 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS grp, 'AZ', 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS grp, 'IA', 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS grp, 'NJ', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS grp, 'NH', 3 FROM DUAL),
    bset AS
        -- In BSET we convert the ASET records into comma separated values
        (  SELECT grp, LISTAGG( state, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY priority) AS set1
             FROM aset
         GROUP BY grp),
    cset ( grp
         , set1
         , set2
         , pos ) AS
        -- CSET breaks our comma separated values up into multiple rows
        -- Each row adding the next CSV value
        (SELECT grp                                                         AS grp
              , set1                                                        AS set1
              , SUBSTR( set1 || ',', 1, INSTR( set1 || ',', ',' ) - 1 )     AS set2
              , 1                                                           AS pos
           FROM bset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT grp              AS grp
              , set1             AS set1
              , SUBSTR( set1 || ','
                      , 1
                      ,   INSTR( set1 || ','
                               , ','
                               , 1
                               , pos + 1 )
                        - 1 )    AS set2
              , pos + 1          AS pos
           FROM cset
          WHERE INSTR( set1 || ','
                     , ','
                     , 1
                     , pos + 1 ) > 0)
  SELECT grp, set2
    FROM cset
ORDER BY grp, pos;
```