# Another Combination

Tags: oracle, plsql, combinations, hierarchical-query

Very similar to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538295/sets-from-a-single-table-grouped-by-a-column), now I want only the, "full combination," for a group in order of priority.  So, from this source table:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| GROUP | State | Priority |
+-------+-------+----------+
|   1   |  MI   |     1    |
|   1   |  IA   |     2    |
|   1   |  CA   |     3    |
|   1   |  ND   |     4    |
|   1   |  AZ   |     5    |
|   2   |  IA   |     2    |
|   2   |  NJ   |     1    |
|   2   |  NH   |     3    |

And so on...
```

I need a query that returns:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| GROUP |     COMBINATION     |
+-------+---------------------+
|   1   | MI, IA, CA, ND, AZ  |
|   2   | NJ, IA, NH          |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Thanks for the help, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `listagg()` ordering by priority within the group.

```
SELECT "GROUP",
       listagg("STATE", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "PRIORITY")
       FROM "ELBAT"
       GROUP BY "GROUP";
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a88b242317e4c67d1f79c4a6ce5dc3f3)

Comment: Four lines.  Wow, that's fantastic.  Thank you very much!